# Can't access motion cam on my raspberry pi from outside

Tags: raspbian, webcam, port-forwarding

I have been struggling with this for whole day. I have a Microsoft web cam connected to my raspberry pi 3 with ip of `192.168.0.17`, and listening port of `446`. Based on the documentation I have the following motion conf setting:

```
daemon on

stream_port 6789

stream_quality 50

stream_motion off

stream_localhost off

webcontrol_port 8081

webcontrol_localhost off

webcontrol_html_output on
```

going to `192.168.0.17:6789` works and I see the cam, but I can't view the cam from out side my network.

I have Spectrum technicolor tc8715d router/modem with following port forwarding and and port triggering setting:

[image]

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong. Let me mention that I have Apache2 running on the pi as well and when I type my external ip address `http://76.155.#.#:446` I can see the Apache2 Debian Default Page, so I know the ip forwarding is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting this as answer as can't add comment yet. Without being familiar with your router it looks to me like you are forwarding port 446, but also have triggers set for 446 and 6789.  Have tried adding an explicit forwarding rule for port 6789?

Having checked the manual for your router (https://www.timewarnercable.com/content/dam/residential/pdfs/support/internet/ModemUserGuides/technicolor-tc8715d-userguide.pdf).  It's clear that port triggering is not the mechanism you need here.  You can delete the existing port trigger rule you have.

You'll need to set a fixed IP address to the Raspberry pi and port forward to  the streaming port 6789 as well as 446: it's an incoming connection which needs to be port forwarded: triggers only work with outgoing connections to open additional incoming ports (i.e. dynamic port forwarding). As the Pi is not making outbound connections from port 6789 then the trigger won't be activated.

The confusion has probably arisen due to equating 'streaming' with 'broadcasting'.  The streaming port only 'streams' output in response to incoming connection requests: it doesn't continually transmit to all stations.

Comment: Hi Charemer, yes, I tried that but no luck. I am not too familiar with ip forwarding and triggering. But I need both to accomplish this.  right?

Comment: From the manual for your router: Port triggering rules will only be activated if a local device is sending traffic over one of the trigger ports. So there must 
be 
outbound traffic first.

Port triggering rules forward the traffic to any device that has initiated the communication while port forwarding only forward
s 
to a specified fixed IP.

Port triggering rules allow you to translate the port numbers. This means that the incoming port can differ from the target 
port.

Comment: Charemer, Thanks. I follow your advice and it works. You are right, I don't need Trigger port.  and I  added the 6789 to forwarding. I can see my cam from outside my network.  Thanks again